# How to make the mongoose data after populating

Tags: node.js, mongoose

for example i have done the populate the data and i don't want the entity at which it's populated for example:

```
 {
        "gstin": "27AAATW4187E2UW",
        "company_name": "TATA_AUTOCOMP ",
        "status": "Hold",
        "createdBy": {
            "name": "xyz123",
            "email": "xyz@yahoo.com",
            "mobile_number": 7972512892
        }
    }
]
```

right now my data looks like above but i don't want the populated information i want my data just like that anyone help me .

```
 {
        "gstin": "27AAATW4187E2UW",
        "company_name": "TATA_AUTOCOMP ",
        "status": "Hold",


        "name": "abcd",
        "email": "xyz@gmail.com",
        "mobile_number": 1234567890
    
}
```

]

Answer (score 0):

in your query when use .populate you can use select and when application run your query just return selected parameters like this :

```
Model
.findOne({ _id: 'bogus' })
.populate('friendsRequestList', 'name email')
```

and if you want all result in one level in json you must edit your result with .map .forEach and ....